# При нажатие на картинку , она должна сплывать в большем размере. Все ок, но вот как ее подвинешь в центр, часть правого края серый

Tags: html, jquery, css

При нажатие на картинку , она должна сплывать в большем размере. Все ok, но вот как ее подвинешь в центр, часть правого края серый.

Может я слеп, но совсем не вижу проблемы. Не замена цвета, ничего не помогает, просто обрезается и все.

Jquery v3.3.1

Код, а именно скрипт и его стили не мои. Сам совсем новичок в этом. 
Всё что относится к проблеме ( код ) прикрепил. + скрин

UPD: Методом "тыка" решил, почему то в свойстве `.popup_bg` , а именно `width 100%` - не являлось 100 проц. Как только ты вводишь 150% затемняет весь фон и все нормально.При этом, если нет данного свойства, картинку расширенную закрыть нельзя.(скорее всего из-за скрипта)

Буду рад, если расскажите почему именно так :)

[image: Пример проблемы]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image").click(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var src = img.attr('src');
    $("body").append("<div class='popup'>" +
      "<div class='popup_bg'></div>" +
      "<img src='" + src + "' class='popup_img' />" +
      "</div>");
    $(".popup").fadeIn(800);
    $(".popup_bg").click(function() {
      $(".popup").fadeOut(800);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".popup").remove();
      }, 800);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  /* margin:30px;  */
  /* float:left; */
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.popup_img {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  max-height: 94%;
  max-width: 94%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 300px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup_bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.699);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="b3">
  <div class="in3">
    <div class="content3">
      <h2>Your thoughts</h2>
      <div class="audio1">
        <div class="cover1">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000" class="image" width="280px" height="280px" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <p class="nameCover1">Citizen — Yellow Love</p>
        </div>
        <audio src="6666.mp3" controls>Citizen — Yellow Love</audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Air Спасибо за правку

Comment: @Air ???  Почему? Мне нужен ответ, но я не знаю решения. Куда мне еще его задовать ?

Comment: @air т.е. ты сделал ?

Comment: @air не знаешь в чем мб проблема?

Comment: Anton,  я так понимаю, что элемент `class='popup'` должен раскрываться на весь экран?

Comment: @air да, я уже методом "тыка" решил, почему то свойстве .popup_bg  , а именно width 100% - не являлось 100 проц. Как только ты ввел 150% затемняет весь фон и все нормально. Впервые такое вижу, но инетересно. При этом, если нет данного свойства, картинку расширенную закрыть нельзя.

Comment: Так у вас прямо написано "отступ справа 300 пикселей" в `.popup`: `right: 300px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image").click(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var src = img.attr('src');
    $("body").append("<div class='popup'>" +
      "<div class='popup_bg'></div>" +
      "<img src='" + src + "' class='popup_img' />" +
      "</div>");
    $(".popup").fadeIn(800);
    $(".popup_bg").click(function() {
      $(".popup").fadeOut(800);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".popup").remove();
      }, 800);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup_bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.699);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup_img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="b3">
  <div class="in3">
    <div class="content3">
      <h2>Your thoughts</h2>
      <div class="audio1">
        <div class="cover1">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000" class="image" width="280px" height="280px" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <p class="nameCover1">Citizen — Yellow Love</p>
        </div>
        <audio src="6666.mp3" controls>Citizen — Yellow Love</audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да, отлично! Спасибо за помощь! Все работает, как нужно :)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста